# My Rubocop doesn't like => e in Ruby error handling. Isn't => e standard?

Tags: ruby, error-handling, coding-style, rubocop

Rubocop doesn't seem to like how I am handling my error. What should I do?

```
Lint/UselessAssignment: Useless assignment to variable - e.
    rescue *exceptions_list => e
```

It is for the piece of code below:

```
  def get_request(url_args = {})
    http_connection(url_builder(url_args[:url], url_args[:page]))
  rescue *exceptions_list => e
    raise "#{e.message}"
  end
```

The `*exceptions_list` that you see there is defined in a private method:

```
  private

    def exceptions_list
      [
        Net::HTTPBadResponse,
        Net::HTTPHeaderSyntaxError,
        Net::ProtocolError,
        Errno::ECONNRESET,
        Errno::EINVAL,
        Timeout::Error,
        EOFError,
        SocketError
      ]
    end
```

To avoid the rescue line being too long.

Question: 
Having `=> e` is pretty standard for error handling no? What should I do?

Thank you very much in advance! =)

Comment: Tell rubocop to shut up with `#rubocop:disable Lint/UselessAssignment`? _Sidenote:_ `raise "#{e.message}"` should be `raise e.message` (or even better `raise e`, which makes the whole `rescue` redundant.)

Comment: it seems like rubocop is wrong here, it's not useless assignment (you use the variable on the next line)

Comment: Thanks Mudasobwa. Can you elaborate more on the redundant rescue bit? I don't understand.

How do i stop the program from crashing if I don't put a rescue block.

Comment: It's not you putting in a rescue block that's a problem; it's putting a rescue block with a raise that makes it crash anyway making it useless. BTW, it would really help if you could craft a minimal example that we could run and see the same problem (your example depends on too much of your own code, and when i tried trimming it down i wasn't getting the result you did)

Comment: My RuboCop doesn't complain. Are you running the latest version?

Comment: I see. I tried it and get what you mean @Armadan. I wont use raise. I'll see what I can do after the rescue to make sure that it doesn't crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example does not give `Lint/UselessAssignment` from rubocop, not at least with version `0.55.0`

The UselessAssignment usually comes from something like this:

```
def do_things
  ..
rescue *exception_list => e # Useless assignment, e is never used in the block below.
  puts "it failed :("
end
```

To fix this, you can remove the assignment if you're not using the raised exception for anything:

```
def do_things
  ..
rescue *exception_list
  puts "it failed and i don't care why :D"
end
```

Comment: Thanks Kimmo! Horay happy!